# Inserting all characters from ASCII table into one field

Tags: sql, oracle

I am testing my script which is automatically making a csv report from my queries and there are some non printable characters which make lots of errors in my column seperation... (characters like carriage return,new line etc)

I would like to insert all characters from an ascii table (http://www.asciitable.com/) into one of my field, so i can see exactly which characters are causing problems.

How could i do this easily?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select level -1 as N, chr(level-1) as chr
from dual connect by level <= 256;
```

This query produces 256 rows, each with 1 character.

```sql
select listagg(chr(level-1)) within group (order by level) as str
from dual connect by level <= 256;
```

And this one concatenates all characters into one string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CHR` function with a row generator.

If you want the printable characters (and not all the control characters) then you can use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value VARCHAR2(200) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT LISTAGG( CHR( ascii ), NULL ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ascii )
FROM  (
  SELECT LEVEL AS ascii
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 127
)
WHERE ascii IN (
         9, /* Horizontal Tab*/
        10, /* Line Feed */
        11, /* Vertical Tab */
        12, /* Form Feed */
        13  /* Carriage Return */
      )
OR    ascii >= 32;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b6b5c37578b43f8e043e567b99069a6)*

Or, if you want all 128 characters you can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
SELECT LISTAGG( CHR( LEVEL - 1 ), NULL ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY LEVEL )
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 128
```

*(This will include the `NUL` character first in the string and may cause issues as it is typically used as a string terminator and low-level string functions may not work properly on the string as they'll see the string terminator and assume that the string has terminated.)*

Answer (score 0):

As for CSV definition, it is not achievable due to a character acting as a separator. However, you can get it in two fields:

**Python script:** (create dummy file)

```
# Create string with all 128 ASCII characters
s = ""
for i in range(128):
  s += chr(i)

# Save into CSV file
filename = 'myfile.csv'
with open(filename,'w') as file:
  file.write(s)
```

**Note:** in python you can convert an integer to char using `chr(x)`, the inverse process would be `ord(x)`.

Hope this was useful ;)

Comment: This will create a file `myfile.csv` in the folder where you execute the python script